# "Find the Index of the First Occurrence in a String" - Unclear case statement using collectFirst method

Tags: scala, syntax

```
def strStr(haystack: String, needle: String): Int = {
    if (needle == "") {
      0
    } else {
      haystack
        .sliding(needle.length)
        .zipWithIndex
        .collectFirst({
          case (`needle`, y) => y
        })
        .getOrElse(-1)
    }
  }
```

Why an argument "needle" in such brackets in the row: needle case (`needle`, y) => y? Why doesn't it work without such brackets? Could someone explain this line to me?

I did try to debug, but it's impossible to see the clear result of step by step running

Comment: Just making sure: you know that `haystack.indexOf(needle)` finds location of a substring in a string?

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm asking about particular method "collectFirst" and the construction of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backquotes (backticks) in the pattern matching in Scala allow to use declared before variables (parameters, etc.) to be matched against, i.e. `` (`needle`, y) `` means to match element against value in the `needle` variable. I.e. `zipWithIndex` will result in tuples `(String, Int)` which will be matched against `needle` value and index will be assigned into `y`. If you remove the backquotes it will just assign the first tuple element to "local" `needle` variable.

This basically an equivalent of following pattern match with pattern guard:

```
.collectFirst({
     case (n, y) if n == needle => y
})
```

From the [spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#stable-identifier-patterns) for 2.11:

> **Stable Identifier Patterns**
> ...
> To resolve the syntactic overlap with a variable pattern, a stable identifier pattern may not be a simple name starting with a lower-case letter. *However, it is possible to enclose such a variable name in backquotes; then it is treated as a stable identifier pattern.*

> Consider the following function definition:

```scala
def f(x: Int, y: Int) = x match {
  case y => ...
}
```

> Here, `y` is a variable pattern, which matches any value. If we wanted to turn the pattern into a stable identifier pattern, this can be achieved as follows:

```scala
def f(x: Int, y: Int) = x match {
  case `y` => ...
}
```

> Now, the pattern matches the `y` parameter of the enclosing function `f`. That is, the match succeeds only if the `x` argument and the `y` argument of `f` are equal.

Read more:

- [Scala pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html)
- [match expressions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/control-structures.html#match-expressions)